# Split image into chunks

Tags: android

I am attempting to split an image into pieces, lets say for example 16 chunks (4x4).Once i split the image how can i display these chunk image as a whole.

Should I use a bitmap or a drawable? Is there a method to split or will I have to make a custom method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bitmap because it holds pixel of the image which will be good for you for future use, if you are willing to display that image.

for example ---->

```
 Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
   ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
   iv.setImageBitmap(bm);
```

-**-----------------------------------EDITED PART--------------------------------------------**

if you want to send image from place to another(one device to another), you to convert it into byte array like this --->

```
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
 ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
 bm.compress(Bitmap.Compress.JPEG, 100, baos);
 byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
```

and then send this to the other device.

Comment: can you please show me with an example.Actually i want to know how can i split the image into chunks and then display the whole image using these chunks.

Comment: why you want it to break it in chunks nd then display and the example code line I had given is the right thing to do, try it first buddy if problem comes post it I'll try to solve it. And if my answer helped you accept it or upvote it.

Comment: Actually i have add NFC support in my app initially on taping two devices i transfer text from one device to another.Now i want to transfer image instead of text.So for that at first i have to split images into chunk and than send it one after another..so thats why i want these

Comment: Yeh Rock u r right..Actually i have tried this but how to implement it in my code, i am not able to get it..the code i have used for transferring text is shown in my edit part..can u please check where and how can i implement ur code so the image transfer is done..

Comment: Sorry Anshuman I am unable to understand your logic so I can't help you after this bro. Really sorry.

Comment: But if my answer helped you little bit so please upvote so that other people with problem can get help from this answer.

Comment: actually i mean to say once i convert the image into the byte array how can i send it into another device..some medium is required like NFC or Blurtooth.so how that can be done

Comment: You can send it to a server and from there redirect it to the another device.

Comment: ok..thanks actually i want to transfer the image using NFC..so do u have any idea for that

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4167/discussion-between-anshuman-and-rocker)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Canvas`, with drawing functionality, splitting it into chunks and set each to 4x4 `ImageView`.

@note:

- as in my experiences, `Bitmap` will give better performance than `Drawable`.
- reduce image size and quality enough to display on screen first, then splitting and setting to `ImageView`.

You can refer to my list of image processing article to get some idea about it. Practically, it's not so hard :)